# How to pass arguments to a Serializer in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer as:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    skip_place = True
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=None)
    place = serializers.CharField(max_length=None,required=False)
```

`def validate_place(self,value):
        if not skip_place and len(value)<=0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Place is required.")`

Now observe `skip_place`. If I call the `DataSerializer` instance as:

`DataSerializer(data=data, skip_place=False)`

Then it should validate over `place` as in the code.

But I was not able to pass the argument `skip_place=True`. I get an error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_place'`

Comment: Did you indent your code correctly?. Looks like `validate_place` is a method of  `DataSerializer ` class. But currently it is written as a module level function.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Sorry, recorrected. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can override the **init** method of serializer, pop the value from there and assign into variable.

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   skip_place = True
   name = serializers.CharField(max_length=None)
   place = serializers.CharField(max_length=None,required=False)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.skip_place = kwargs.pop('skip_place ', False)
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def validate_place(self,value):
     if not self.skip_place and len(value)<=0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Place is required.")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can send it with [including extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

In view;

```
DataSerializer(data=data, context={'skip_place': True}) # or False
```

In serializer;

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=None)
    place = serializers.CharField(max_length=None,required=False)

    def validate_place(self,value):
        skip_place = self.context.get("skip_place") # <- here we use self.context to get extra args
        if not skip_place and len(value)<=0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Place is required.")
```